# gensim LdaMulticore not multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, lda, gensim

When I run gensim's `LdaMulticore` model on a machine with 12 cores, using:

```
lda = LdaMulticore(corpus, num_topics=64, workers=10)
```

I get a logging message that says

```
using serial LDA version on this node
```

A few lines later, I see another loging message that says

```
training LDA model using 10 processes
```

When I run top, I see 11 python processes have been spawned, but 9 are sleeping, I.e. only one worker is active.  The machine has 24 cores, and is not overwhelmed by any means.  Why isn't LdaMulticore running in parallel mode?

Comment: One reason might due to the [slow loading of the `corpus`](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/288). Test your code to see how much time it takes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, make sure you [have installed a fast BLAS library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/distributed.html), because most of the time consuming stuff is done inside low-level routines for linear algebra.

On my machine the [`gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaMulticore`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html) can use up all the 20 cpu cores with `workers=4` during training. Setting workers larger than this didn't speed up the training. [One reason might be the `corpus` iterator is too slow to use LdaMulticore effectively](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/288).

You can try to use [`ShardedCorpus`](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/sharded_corpus.py) to serialize and replace the `corpus`, which should be much faster to read/write. Also, simply zipping your large `.mm` file so it takes up less space (=less I/O) may help too. E.g.,

```
mm = gensim.corpora.MmCorpus(bz2.BZ2File('enwiki-latest-pages-articles_tfidf.mm.bz2'))
lda = gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=100, workers=4)
```

Comment: My problem was indeed because of an I/O bottleneck in loading the corpus.  I imagine that using `ShardedCorpus` might help -- I'll try that next time.  For me, simply pre-loading the whole corpus into memory first (machine has almost a 1 T ram), solved the problem.  Pre-loading is *way* faster than loading docs on demand.  I'll try your other suggestions next time!

Comment: doesn't `corpora.MmCorpus('some_corpus.mm')` pre-loads the corpus in memory? i am stuck in this issue too, where the logger says `using serial LDA version on this node` and then nothing..

Comment: Had a similar problem, `LdaMulticore` worked in one environment and not another, compared packages and found that removing scikit-learn (with llvm-openmp - probable source of issue) solved it.

Comment: This is old, but can confirm that  conflicts were my issue as well. Creating a conda environment without scikitlearn solved the problem.