# Gensim LdaMulticore is not multiprocessing properly (using just 4 workers)

Tags: python, lda, gensim, topic-modeling

I am using Gensim's LDAMulticore to perform LDA. I have around 28M small documents (around 100 characters each).

I have given workers argument to be 20 but the top shows it using only 4 processes. There are some discussions around it that it might be slow in reading corpus like:
[gensim LdaMulticore not multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929680/gensim-ldamulticore-not-multiprocessing) 
https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/288

But both of them uses MmCorpus . Although my corpus is completely in memory. I have machine with very large RAM (250 GB) and loading the corpus in memory takes around 40 GB. But even after that LDAMulticore is using just 4 processes. I created the corpus as:

`corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]`

I am not able to understand what can be the limiting factor here?

Comment: i have the same issue. the logger becomes silent after the line "using serial LDA version on this node"

Comment: I get a similar issue when running on a Mac with vecLib. I solved that using OpenBLAS. Not sure if it could be related to that (the BLAS library and the way multithreading works on your platform).

Answer (score 1):

**I would check what is the batch size you use**

I found that in cases the **Batch X n_workers** is **greater** than **number of documents**, I cannot utilize all the available workers I have. 
This make sense as you give each worker a number of docs per pass. You might "starve" some of them if the batch value is not considered.

I am not sure it solves your specific problem, but is indeed the reason many people mentioned the multicore does not "work" as expected in terms of multiprocessing